# How can I mirror a SharePoint 2007 site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How does one go about mirroring a SharePoint 2007 site?

The mirror doesn't need to be nice and pretty; it just needs to be presentable and readable. Also, I need all the shared documents to be copied as well.

We used to have WinHTTrack to mirror the SharePoint site, but that broke a few months ago due to some of our recent security changes.

I tried the username@password:domain method but that resulted in no luck.

Comment: What's the "username@password:domain method"?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of WinHTTrack (Version 3.44-5, 02/11/2012)?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: this: http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#QM6

Comment: @techie007 Yes, I tried the latest version, no luck.

Comment: @aZn137 The only way I can apply that to SharePoint is the use of the SMB proxy for a SharePoint library (connecting a SharePoint library as a network volume).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I've opted for WinHTTrack because I need the Sharepoint to be offline and static. The SP consists of a bunch of procedures and documents for the on-call techs when there's an emergency, which assumes the main servers are offline. Would this work?

Comment: redundancy ? for what? what is your goal to do this?